# Objectify - Order by reference

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

is it possible in Objectify to order by a field of a referenced object?

Example:

```
public class Foo {
    @Id private long id;
    @Index Ref<AnObject> ref;
}

public class AnObject {{
    @Id private long id;
    @Index name;
}
```

Then I try to do this query and it's not working:

```
Query<Foo> query =  ofy().load().type(Foo.class)
        .limit(Constants.DATASTORE_LIMIT)
        .order("ref.name");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not. This is not something supported by the datastore. It can't do joins.

There are basically two ways around that limitation:

1. Denormalize and put an indexed copy of the 'name' data in your Foo object. You can do this somewhat automatically with an `@OnSave` method. The downside is that you need to remember to update the data in both places if it changes.
2. Do the work of the query planner yourself. Query for the relevant AnObjects, then query for the relevant Foos.

Comment: Datastore is missing some important features :/. Maybe they do it that way bec it's supposed to be done faster the way you say or in the code itself?

Also I've noticed it doesn't order numbers properly, if I order for example 22 and 3, it'll get 22 first and then 3. It doesn't count the full number or something like that

Comment: The datastore has a constraint that all operations scale with the size of the result set, not with the size of the data set. So it doesn't do joins. It can be an infuriating limitation compared to working with SQL. WRT sorting - you need to explicitly request a sort, and be sure you aren't storing the numbers as string.